# How to authenticate multiple sectors in MIFARE classic 1K?

Tags: c#, mifare

i would like to know, is there any way that we can authenticate sector one by one in MIFARE classic 1k, by which i will able to write data in multiple blocks at the same time. In current scenario i am able to authenticate one sector at a time. Like for example if i am authenticating  sector 10 ( any block 36,37 or 38). So i am able to write the data in sector 36 37 and 38, but i want this that, if i can authenticate sector 10 first then write its all blocks and then sector 11 and write its all blocks. Any c# code by this it can be done. i have created a function in c# but it is for only to authenticate 1 sector.

Comment: So you already found out that the process is to authenticate a sector, write data to its blocks, authenticate the next sector, write data to its blocks, etc. What's the actual problem that you have with that?

Comment: i got the solutions to declare authentication of sector 1 by one     string blkAuth = "36";
            string blk1 = "36";
            string blk2 = "37";
            string blk3 = "38";

            string val1 = Passid_txt.Text; //username
            string fullname = Name_txt.Text;
            string val2 = fullname.Substring(0, 14);  //validity 
            string val3 = fullname.Substring(14,6);

            write_authenticaion(blkAuth,blk1,blk2,blk3,val1,val2,val3);
where write_authentication is a class including APDUs for authentication for each sector.

Comment: So what's wrong with using that method for both sectors?

Comment: yes i have different method for each sector and its working fine now